# xcode - Bot creation failed with error: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made

Tags: xcode, ssl, bots, osx-server

I am trying to create a bot on my server running 10.9, and I keep getting the following error:

> Bot creation failed with error: An SSL error has occurred and a secure
>   connection to the server cannot be made.

I just updated my SSL cert from the self signed to one from GoDaddy. My `https://servername` connects fine with a green https.

How do I get it to recognize my certificate?

Comment: Where is the client running, and what language is it written in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never was able to find a solution. I ended up doing a clean install, add my GoDaddy SSL certificates again, and the problem was resolved.